# python convert prediction result into one hot

Tags: python

I run python neural network prediction expecting one hot result and got back numbers as follow:

```
[[0.33058667182922363, 0.3436272442340851, 0.3257860243320465], 
[0.32983461022377014, 0.3487854599952698, 0.4213798701763153], 
[0.3311253488063812, 0.3473075330257416, 0.3215670585632324], 
[0.38368630170822144, 0.35151687264442444, 0.3247968554496765], 
[0.3332786560058594, 0.343686580657959, 0.32303473353385925]]
```

how can I convert the array into one hot result, i.e.

```
[[0,1,0],
[0,0,1],
[0,1,0],
[1,0,0]
[0,1,0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

By one hot result I assume you want max value of each sub-list to be `1` and rest to be `0` (based on the pattern in current result). You may do it using *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> [[int(item == max(sublist)) else 0 for item in sublist] for sublist in my_list]
#      ^  converts bool value returned by `==` into `int`. True -> 1, False -> 0
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

where `my_list` is your initial list.

But in the above approach, you will be calculating `max()` each time while iteration over sub-list. Better way will be to do it like:

```
def get_hot_value(my_list):
    max_val = max(my_list)
    return [int(item == max_val) for item in my_list]

hot_list = [get_hot_value(sublist) for sublist in my_list]
```

---

**Edit:** If you are supposed to have just one `1` in the list (in case of more than 1 element of maximum value), you may modify the `get_hot_value` function as:

```
def get_hot_value(my_list):
    max_val, hot_list, is_max_found = max(my_list), [], False
    for item in my_list:
        if item == max_val and not is_max_found:
            hot_list.append(1)
        else:
            hot_list.append(0)
            is_max_found = True
    return hot_list
```

Comment: Good solution. But I would consider a situation with more than one max value which will produce more than one `1` in the row.

Comment: I believe it should be more than `1` in that case. As I mentioned I do not know the definition of *hot result*, but I guessed it based on the pattern. If it has to be one. above solution could be modified

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych : I think that was the valid scenario based on ***one** hot* in question. Made an edit

Comment: That would work. But `1 not in hot_list` increases complexity up to n^2 (if it matters).

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych: Yes, it would have. Updated the answer using flag :)

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions are good, and solve the problem. Alternatively, if you have numpy,

```
import numpy as np
n = [[0.33058667182922363, 0.3436272442340851, 0.3257860243320465],
     [0.32983461022377014, 0.3487854599952698, 0.4213798701763153],
     [0.3311253488063812, 0.3473075330257416, 0.3215670585632324],
     [0.38368630170822144, 0.35151687264442444, 0.3247968554496765],
     [0.3332786560058594, 0.343686580657959, 0.32303473353385925]]

max_indices = np.argmax(n,axis=1)

final_values = [n[i] for i in max_indices]
```

argmax is able to find the index of the maximum value in that row, then you just need to do one list comprehension over that. Should be pretty fast I guess?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this:

```
n = [[0.33058667182922363, 0.3436272442340851, 0.3257860243320465],
     [0.32983461022377014, 0.3487854599952698, 0.4213798701763153],
     [0.3311253488063812, 0.3473075330257416, 0.3215670585632324],
     [0.38368630170822144, 0.35151687264442444, 0.3247968554496765],
     [0.3332786560058594, 0.343686580657959, 0.32303473353385925]]

hot_results = []

for row in n:
    hot_index = row.index(max(row))
    hot_result = [0] * len(row)
    hot_result[hot_index] = 1
    hot_results.append(hot_result)

print(hot_results)
```

Comment: One of the simple and good approach to get this done in case only single `1` is required in the list